# Transform $dx/dt$ to $dr/dt$ polar coordinates

Tags: proof-verification, polar-coordinates

I've had to screenshot the question and post it as a photo
[image: Photo of question]

Comment: You are using some weird unicode characters in your post

Comment: You have a lot of characters that render as a black diamond with a question mark inside.  What are they?  When I show TeX commands two of them render as an open square.

Comment: in which lines?

Comment: In the first two equations, and also in the equation right after you give the parameterization of $x$ and $y$

Comment: On the right-hand side of the first equation, I see$$-x-y-??(x^2+y^2)??x$$ with black diamonds around the question marks.

Comment: I can't see no black diamond, I've posted a photo of it stead of how it looks on my computer hopefully that's fixed the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in writing $$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{dr}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}\\\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{dr}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt}$$ This is **not** true. Use the multivariable chain rule here to get $$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial r }{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$Then sub in your two equations, as well as $$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}={\cos \theta}\\\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}={\sin \theta}$$ to get the correct final result

Comment: if $x=rcos(\theta)$ then $r=\frac{x}{cos(\theta)}$ then taking the partial derviate with respect to x shouldnt it be $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$=$\frac{1}{cos(\theta)}$

Comment: @ricky $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ means the partial derivative with respect to $x$, while fixing $y$, so $r$ must be written in terms of $x$ and $y$. So $$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{r\cos\theta}{r}=\cos\theta$$

Comment: Thank you, makes sense

Answer (score 2):

The transformations can be written as

$$\tag 1  r^2 = x^2 + y^2~~ \text{and}~~ \theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

Differentiating $(1)$

$$r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \implies 2 r r' = 2x x' + 2y y' \implies r ' = \dfrac{x x' + y y'}{r}$$

Substituting $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$, we have

$$\begin{align} r' &= \dfrac{x x' + y y'}{r} \\&=  \dfrac{(r \cos \theta \left(-r \cos \theta \left(r^2 \right)-r \sin \theta +r \cos \theta\right)+r \sin \theta \left(-r \sin \theta \left(r^2 \right)+r \sin \theta+r \cos \theta)\right)}{r}\\ &= r(1-r^2)\end{align}$$

We can also derive

$$\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \implies \theta' = \dfrac{xy'-yx'}{r^2}$$

Make the appropriate substitutions, do some trig simplifications and cleanup to derive  $\theta'$.